# Methods for showing that the fundamental group of a space is finite

Tags: algebraic-topology, vector-bundles, fundamental-groups

My motivation for this question stems from needing to show that the fundamental groups of the projectivised tangent bundles of $\mathbb{S}^2$ and $\mathbb{RP}^2$ are finite. I am aware of a proof that shows their respective fundamental groups have order 4 and 8 respectively, which is done through explicitly calculating $\mathbb{P}T\mathbb{S}^2$ and $\mathbb{P}T\mathbb{RP}^2$.

In this paper, the exact values 4 and 8 are used later on. For my purposes, I don't need the exact values - just the fact they are finite. Are there general methods for computing when the fundamental group of a space is finite, aside from explicitly calculating it? Is it perhaps obvious in either of the cases above?

Comment: Would you mind including a link to the paper you mention?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a result that can sometimes be used to show that the fundamental group of a space is finite:

> If $X$ is compact and has a universal cover, say $\tilde{X}$, then $\pi_1(X)$ is finite if and only if $\tilde{X}$ is compact.

Comment: Ah yes I had used that result just a few minutes ago! I'm not sure how easy it would be to show the universal covers of $\mathbb{P}T\mathbb{S}^2$ and $\mathbb{P}T\mathbb{RP}^2$ are compact in my case though. Thanks

Comment: Actually would this just follow from the fact that $\mathbb{P}T\mathbb{S}^2$ and $\mathbb{P}T\mathbb{RP}^2$ are compact and Hausdorff?

Comment: No, consider $\mathbb S^1$. @jl2

Comment: We'd need the additional requirement that $p^{-1}(x)$ is finite for all $x$ (where $p$ is the universal cover), right?

Comment: @jl2 That would do it (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/323711/fiber-bundle-is-compact-if-base-and-fiber-are), but those fibers are in bijection with the fundamental group -- so you would have to know beforehand that the fundamental groups are finite.

Comment: Do you know a textbook that proves this?