# Do Borel subgroups make sense in an arbitrary algebraic group. When is $G/B$ projective?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let us be over $\Bbb C$.

It seems that in an arbitrary algebraic group, it makes sense to talk about solvable subgroups and connected subgroups. Then, it seems that the concept of a Borel subgroup holds in an arbitrary algebraic group.

Is $G/B$ projective then, if we consider an arbitrary algebraic group $G$, or does this not make sense unless $G$ is atleast reductive? When does it make sense? Is there something weaker than reductivity that gives us this? The proofs I have seen for projectivity of $G/B$ rely it seems on affine algebraic groups embedding into $\text{GL}(n,\Bbb C)$, so it seems we do at least need $G$ to be an affine algebraic group.

Comment: $B$ will contain the solvable radical, hence the problem reduces to the semisimple case which you already know how to handle. If not, take a look in any book on algebraic groups, say, Borel's.

Answer (score 1):

Let $G$ be reduced, connected but not necessarily affine algebraic group over a perfect field(and hence smooth), Barsotti-Chevalley theorem says that there exists a (unique) connected normal affine algebraic subgroup say $H$ of $G$ such that $G/H$ is an abelian variety. Now Let $B$ be a borel subgroup of $H$, then $H/B$ is a projective variety. We now claim that $B$ is the Borel subgroup in the sense that $G/B$ is complete.

Claim 1 : $ G(\mathbb{C}) \rightarrow (G/H)(\mathbb{C}) $ is a locally trivial fiber bundle with fibers $H(\mathbb{C})$.

Claim 2 : $ (G/B)(\mathbb{C}) \rightarrow (G/H)(\mathbb{C}) $ is a locally trivial fiber bundle with fibers $(H/B)(\mathbb{C})$.

Note that claim 1 and claim 2 follow once we know that the quotients in the algebraic sense also turn out to be quotients in the sense of lie groups on $\mathbb{C}-$points. Note that

Claim 3 : $(G/B)(\mathbb{C})$ is compact.

This follows from here [Fiber bundle is compact if base and fiber are](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/323711/fiber-bundle-is-compact-if-base-and-fiber-are)
and the fact that $A, H/B$ is a projective variety and hence $A(\mathbb{C}), H/B(\mathbb{C})$ is compact.

Claim 4 : $G/B$ is a proper over $\mathbb{C}$

Claim 4 follows from chow's lemma. For a proof look at section 7 of GAGA by Serre.

So $G/B$ will be projective once we know the fact that the quotient of a group is quasi-projective.

Let $B'$ be a maximal connected solvable subgroup of $G$, then $B' \supset B$ and hence $G/B \rightarrow G/B'$ is surjective and thus $G/B'$ is also proper over $\mathbb{C}$. Once again So $G/B'$ will be projective once we know the fact that the quotient of a group by a closed subgroup is quasi-projective.

I realize this lacks a lot of details but hopefully this gives an idea as to how this problem can be approached.

Comment: This is very nice ! (+1)

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet Thanks.