# Compactness about fiber bundle

Tags: fiber-bundles

I am working on a problem (problem 10.19 (d)) in John M. Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifold.

Assume that $\pi$: $E$ $\rightarrow$ $M$ is a fiber bundle with model fiber $F$, I need to prove if $E$ is compact, then so are $M$ and $F$.
Clearly, $M$ is compact and if we assume that $M$ is Hausdorff, then it follows easily from part (c) of this problem.
($\pi$: $E$ $\rightarrow$ $M$ is proper iff $F$ is compact.)

(Edited: I think it suffices to assume that $M$ is $T_1$, i.e., singletons are closed, then it follows from the continuity that the fibers are compact.)

However, I have no idea how to proceed in the general case.
Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, I now understand the problem. I will delete all my previous comments.

Comment: It's fine. Thank you very much for the previous discussion.

Comment: I just noticed this question. I think you mean Problem 10-19(d). At the moment, I can't figure out what I was thinking when I wrote that question. I don't see how to prove it without assuming $M$ is at least $T_1$, nor have I been able to come up with a counterexample. If nobody comes up with a better answer in the next couple of days, I'll post a correction to the problem. But I would like to know whether the claim is true or not.

Comment: [Does this answer to your question or not](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/323711/272127)?

Comment: @C.F.G: That question actually addresses the converse of the question the OP asked.

Comment: Ahh again I made a mistake! sorry.

Comment: Hint: use compactness of $M$ to show that there is a nonempty closed subset $Z \subseteq M$ over which $E$ is trivial.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since the author chimed in in the comments, let me record the full answer here.

This is still true without separation assumptions on the base. Indeed, by compactness of $M$ there exists a finite cover $\{U_i \subseteq M\}_{i \in I}$ over which $E$ is trivialised. Without loss of generality we may assume that no strict subset of $\{U_i \subseteq M\}$ covers $M$. Then
$$Z = M \setminus \bigcup_{j \neq i} U_j \subseteq U_i$$
is a nonempty closed subset over which $E$ is trivial, i.e. $E|_Z \cong F \times Z$. Since $E|_Z \subseteq E$ is closed, it is compact, hence so is $F$ since it is the image of the first projection $F \times Z \to F$. $\square$

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry, why the WLOG part is true?

Comment: @C.F.G since $I$ is finite, there is an inclusionwise minimal subset $J \subseteq I$ such that the $U_j$ for $j \in J$ cover. This is only used to show that $Z$ is nonempty, for which there might be other methods.

Comment: @Remy: You meant "that no strict subset of $U_i$ (i.e. $V_i\subset U_i$) covers  $M$" Or "for at least a $k$, $U_i$'s do not cover $M$ for $i\neq k$"?

Comment: @C.F.G apparently my previous wording could be interpreted in two ways, so I have edited for clarification.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry again, I don't want to annoy you, but why $E|_Z$ is closed?

Comment: @C.F.G $\pi$ is continuous

Comment: So your argument works for every sufficiently small closed subset of $M$ and not just $Z$?

Comment: That's the point: you don't need a closed point; any closed subset over which $E$ is trivialised will do. Just construct one.

Comment: Nice proof. It might even be what I had in mind when I wrote the problem; but since I didn't see it at first, I've decided to add a hint to my [correction list](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~lee/Books/ISM/). Thanks for chiming in.