# Why is the quotient by the Borel subgroup compact?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a complex lie group with semisimple lie algebra $g$.

Put $b$ the borel subalgebra (so the sum of $h$ and all the positive roots) for some choices.

One can there is the borel subgroup $B$ with lie algebra $b$ in $G$; given as a the stabilizer of $b$ in the adjoint action. My book claims now that $G/B$ is compact, since it's isomorphic to its image in the Grassmanian (i.e where the adjoint sends $b$) and the Grassmanian is compact. However, how do we know that the image is closed?

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/323711/fiber-bundle-is-compact-if-base-and-fiber-are). It can be used to show that $G/B$ is compact.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Can you expand on this? Where here is a fiber bundle who I control well? And also the directions there seem to go the opposite way; I don't want to show $G$ is compact, I want the quotient

Comment: May I ask what the book is?

Comment: @chikurin Probably harris about lie groups and algebras